# How to get the metadata from a file using ffmpy

Tags: python, ffmpeg

How, using the python package [ffmpy](http://ffmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ffmpy.html), can I get a multimedia file's metadata such as dimensions, duration and bitrate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One needs to use the `FFprobe` functionality while passing the output that usually just streams to the terminal to the stdout:

```
import subprocess
import ffmpy
import json

tup_resp = ffmpy.FFprobe(
    inputs={source_path: None},
    global_options=[
        '-v', 'quiet',
        '-print_format', 'json',
        '-show_format', '-show_streams']
).run(stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

meta = json.loads(tup_resp[0].decode('utf-8'))
```

And now meta is a json dictionary with all the info we could want.

Comment: I can't seem to get this code block example to work. It will work in command shell, but using the FFmpy wrapper I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.
It doesn't seem as though the FFprobe object is returning anything. Tags/Arguments are correct. I made sure to run() on the object with a pipe made for both stdout and stderr. I'm not sure why this is happening..